# Scala - Play: How to bind a form field to a Vector?

Tags: forms, scala, vector, playframework, binding

in Play 2.6 the default Form bindings for repeated elements are `Seq`, `List` and `Set`, for example:

```
Form(
  "name" -> seq(text)
)
```

However I'm using Vector collection type for several scenarios as it has a better overall performance (such as for Index based Access) than the default implementation of `Seq` or `Iterable` which is `List` (Good performance for handling Head or Tail elements Linear time if doing indexed search).

In current Play 2.6 there aren't any default Form bindings for `Vector` or `IndexedSeq` (which defaults to `Vector`).

What is the default approach for mapping a `Vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own mapping like this,

```
def vector[A](mapping: Mapping[A]): Mapping[Vector[A]] =
  RepeatedMapping(mapping).transform(_.toVector, _.toList)
```

and then use it like this,

```
Form(
  "name" -> vector(text)
)
```